# Changing Bootstrap 4 Modal content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm displaying a database (via a HTML table and an Ajax request), and by clicking over a row, I want to display its content within a Modal. I'm displaying several database content via a listbox. Everything looks to work properly, but my only issue is once I displayed one Modal, the other ones have the same content as the first.
I tried to wipe the content of the Modal when it closes, but with no success. Here is my function. If someone could help, it would be much appreciated! :)

I loop through the database and generate each row by doing this:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    //headContent is an Array containing the names of the head columns
    output = "<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='#create-item' aria-hidden='true' onclick='openModal(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + (i+1) + ", headContent);' style='cursor:pointer;'>";

    for (var j=0; j < data[i].length; j ++) {
        output += "<td title='Click on the line to perform action.' style='text-align: center;'>" + data[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
             output += "</tr>";
         $("#resultsAdmContent").append(output); //#resultsAdmContent is an empty DIV
}
```

I was hoping a Modal would be generated everytime I'm clicking on a row, using this function below:

```
    function openModal(dbname, line, titles) {
    var titleTab = [];
    var valueTab = [];

    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "./php/readLine.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { dbname: dbname, line: line },
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i=1; i < data.length; i ++) { // We don't need the 0, because it's the line number
                    data.forEach(function (a) {
                        Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
                            a[key] = Number(a[key]) || a[key]; // Converts String in number (when a number appears)
                        });
                    }); 
                }

            lsTab = data[0];

            var modalBegBlk = "<div class='modal fade' id='create-item' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<div class='modal-content'>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<div class='modal-header'>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Perform action in the database</h4>";
                        modalBegBlk += "<h5 class='control-label' for='title'>Line selected: " + line + "</h5>";
                        modalBegBlk += "</div>";

                        modalContent += modalBegBlk;     

                    for (var k = 1; k < titles.length; k ++) {
                        modalContent += "<div class='modal-body' style='padding:3px;text-align:right;margin-right:33%;'>";
                        modalContent += "<label>" + titles[k] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type='text' id='nameTab" + k + "' name='" + titles[k] + "' value='" + lsTab[k] + "'/>";
                        modalContent += "</div>";
                        titleTab[k] = titles[k];
                        valueTab[k] = lsTab[k];
                    }

                    var modalFooter = "<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='updateRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Update</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='cloneRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Clone</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Delete</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div>";
                    var modalEndBlk = "</div></div></div>";

                    modalContent += modalFooter;
                    modalContent += modalEndBlk;

                    $("#updateDBUI").append(modalContent);  

            },
            error:function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("Reading PHP database went wrong. Error " + request.responseText);
            }
    });
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log("Modal hidden!");
            titles = []; //DOESN'T WORK
            lsTab = []; //DOESN'T WORK
    });
}
```

I don't know how to empty the Modal. I've tried `$(".Modal").empty();` with no effect. Maybe I'm missing something here, or I'm doing it wrong. Help please! Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by `relevant code` ? This is the whole function you see here.

Comment: Yes, everytime. I'm fetching the data with the Ajax request, then want to display the content into the Modal. So, when I display a row of the table, I'm listening for a click as: `onclick='openModal(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ", headContent);'`

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I updated my request with the missing code. Hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new modal each time in jQuery, you should just put one "create-item" modal in your HTML markup..

```
<div class="container" id="updateDBUI">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody id="resultsAdmContent">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="create-item" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Perform action in the database</h4>
                    <h5 id="modalLabel">Line selected:<span id="selectedLine"></span></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, when the AJAX call completes, update the modal parts as needed with what whatever content/data...

```
function openModal(dbname, line) {
    var titleTab = [];
    var valueTab = [];

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "...",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
            // ajax data returned
                for (var i=1; i < data.length; i ++) { // We don't need the 0, because it's the line number
                    data.forEach(function (a) {
                        Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
                            a[key] = Number(a[key]) || a[key]; // Converts String in number (when a number appears)
                        });
                    }); 
                }

            lsTab = data[0];

            // update modal title content
            $('#selectedLine').text(line);

            // update modal body content
            for (var k = 1; k < titles.length; k ++) {
                modalContent += "<label>" + titles[k] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type='text' id='nameTab" + k + "' name='" + titles[k] + "' value='" + lsTab[k] + "'/>";
                titleTab[k] = titles[k];
                valueTab[k] = lsTab[k];
            }
            $('.modal-body').html(modalContent);

            // update footer content
            var modalFooter = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='updateRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Update</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='cloneRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Clone</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteRecord(&quot;" + dbname + "&quot;, " + line + ");'>Delete</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";               
            $('.modal-footer').html(modalFooter);

          },
          error:function(request, status, error) {
              ..
          }// end ajax return
    });
}
```

This way there is one modal where you change its' content each time.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/LDLLNDGRR5

Note: In your code I didn't see `titles=[]` being set anywhere so I don't know what that data looks like, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank You very much! This is working great! :)  BTW, `titles[]` was a parameter in the `openModal(dbname, line, titles)` declaration. I was using it to pass the whole array of headers columns. Your solution works perfectly! :)